# Prisma migration is bad state

Tags: database-migration, prisma

We seem to have gotten our prisma migrations into a bad state. When we get the latest code and run

```
prisma migrate dev
```

we get

> Migration `20210819161149_some_migration` failed to apply cleanly to
> the shadow database.  Error code: P3018 Error: A migration failed to
> apply. New migrations cannot be applied before the error is recovered
> from. Read more about how to resolve migration issues in a production
> database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve
>
> Migration name: 20210819161149_some_migration
>
> Database error code: 1065

All the migrations in source control do match the ones in the `_prisma_migrations` table so I'm not sure why it thinks `20210819161149_some_migration` failed. There is nothing in the `logs` column in `_prisma_migrations` for that record. I think what happened is a developer applied the migration then changed the `migration.sql` for it after the fact.

Anyway, we followed the steps outlined https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve but they don't seem to resolve the issue. It first suggests running

```
prisma migrate resolve --rolled-back "20210819161149_some_migration"
```

but that results in

> Error: P3012
>
> Migration `20210819161149_some_migration` cannot be rolled
> back because it is not in a failed state.

So then we tried to mark it as applied

```
prisma migrate resolve --applied "20210819161149_some_migration"
```

but that results in this error

> Error: P3008
>
> The migration `20210819161149_some_migration` is already
> recorded as applied in the database.

We also tried running

```
 prisma migrate deploy
```

Which gives

> 13 migrations found in prisma/migrations WARNING The following
> migrations have been modified since they were applied:
> 20210819161149_some_migration

but you still get the same issue above when running `prisma migrate dev`.

Is there any way to get prisma happy again without deleting all the data?

Comment: have you tried to use `prisma format` i think will help you!

Comment: @EliasSalom `prisma format` is not relevant or helpful at all for this question.

Answer (score 13):

A possible workaround would involve [baselining your development database](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/baselining) based on your current schema/migration history. You would need a separate backup database and you will lose your existing migration history, but it should retain your data.

Here's what the process would look like

1. Delete all migration history from your `prisma` folder as well as the `_prisma_migrations` table in your database.
2. Create a new backup database.
3. Connect the project to your backup database and run `prisma migrate dev --name baseline_migration` . This will generate a migration matching your current prisma schema.
4. Connect back to your main Database and baseline the generated migration by running `prisma migrate resolve --applied  20210426141759_baseline_migration`  (The numbers at the beginning of your migration name will differ).

The reason you'd be creating a backup database and running the initial baseline migrations in that backup database is because you don't want to lose the data in your main database. I realize this is not an ideal solution, but it might work if it's very important for you to keep your data while retaining your existing dev workflow.

This article on [Adding Prisma Migrate to an existing project](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/add-prisma-migrate-to-a-project/) is also worth a read.

Comment: Great answer. It's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, except

```
prisma migrate resolve --rolled-back "20210819161149_some_migration"
```

resulted in success, but didn't unblock `prisma migrate`.

After half an hour of confusion and pain, I realized I was running `prisma migrate resolve` against the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference this site will provide you the the correct ways of troubleshooting your problem. I got a migration error (P3009) and when i investigate through the generated sql file and found that some syntax issue occured in the generated file and resolved them and fix the migration issue

Answer (score 0):

My advice for tricky situations like this is to go to the `_prisma_migrations` table in the database, find the failed migration row, and delete it. Usually, the failed migration row in the database is the last one when sorted by `started_at` in ascending order. Note that the row will have a `logs` column, which usually contains the reason why the database migration failed. Keep note of the message and then delete the migration row.

Then go to your code, delete the `migration.sql` file and its parent folder (e.g. `/20231212000000_migration_name/migration.sql`), and then try to re-deploy your app.

This should bring you back to your last stable state. Then, you can work from there to assess why your DB migration was problematic.

Answer (score -1):

You can do how it`s described in this short video
https://youtu.be/BIfvmEhbtBE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).