# Prisma - How to fix Migration file after invalid column data value, and migration failed

Tags: mysql, prisma

Updated a column and put in an incorrect value for the varchar length.  This caused the migration file to fail and now it wants to reset the Database and wipe everything out.

```
Error: P3006

Migration `20221205190350_migration_name_here` failed to apply cleanly to the shadow database. 
Error code: P3018
Error:
  A migration failed to apply. New migrations cannot be applied before the error is 
  recovered from. Read more about how to resolve migration issues in a production 
  database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-resolve

Migration name: 20221205190350_migration_name_here

Database error code: 1074

Database error:
  Column length too big for column 'cardJson' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead

Please check the query number 1 from the migration file.
```

That is not an option.

I tried following the documentation to rollback and fix the migration, but it still wants to reset everything.

```
prisma migrate resolve --rolled-back "20221205190350_migration_name_here"
```

Then I updated it to a correct value in the SQL migration file and the schema file and tried to run it but it says it has already been applied (so not sure what the purpose of rolling it back then is?)

I need a way to adjust this migration file so the DB doesn't get reset.  The table itself is empty so that could be dropped if that would help but I do not think any migrations are going to run unless I can find a way to fix this file.

Comment: Can you take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861812/1645620) and apply it to your usecase.